# bigquery standard sql error, invalid timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm playing with some tables in bigquery and I receive this error:

> Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of -62169990264000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch.
>   The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]

Doing the query in legacy sql and sorting ascending, it displays as 0001-11-29 22:15:36 UTC

How does it get transformed into microseconds?

This is the query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  birthdate
FROM
  X
WHERE
  birthdate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  birthdate ASC
```

Comment: show your query that produces error

Comment: changed the details, added now

Answer (score 3):

**`strong text`**Confirming , that in BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(-62169990264000000)
```

produces 0001-11-29 22:15:36 UTC timestamp

whereas in BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(-62169990264000000)
```

produces error:
TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00.

> How does it get transformed in microseconds?

TIMESTAMP
You can describe TIMESTAMP data types as either UNIX timestamps or calendar datetimes. BigQuery stores TIMESTAMP data internally as a UNIX timestamp with **`microsecond precision`**.

See more about [TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#timestamp-type) type

Answer (score 2):

Midnight of January 1 of the year 0001 (the minimum possible timestamp value in standard SQL) is -62135596800000000 in microseconds relative to the UNIX epoch, which is greater than -62169990264000000. I don't have a good explanation for legacy SQL's behavior with that timestamp value, but you can read about some suggestions for dealing with it in standard SQL in [this item on the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=730). We plan to add some content to the migration guide about this timestamp behavior in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar issue using  `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(unix_timestamp_column)` giving me the following exception:

`TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00.`

Turned out that **unix_timestamp_column** had mixed data where at one point timestamp was stored in microseconds and then in milliseconds... 1 millisecond = 1000 microseconds...

`TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1698425168223000)` ~= 53,875 years... Convert to today = UNIX epoch [01/01/1970] + 53,875 years which is >  `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00.`

So I used

```
select
IFNULL(SAFE.TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1698425168223000),TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1698425168223000))
```