# BigQuery standard SQL error, invalid timestamp when date field is not touched at all

Tags: google-bigquery

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195883/bigquery-standard-sql-error-invalid-timestamp) doesn't help me. Although I am having similar issue in a rather simple update query, which looks like below (idea is add sha-256 encoding to legacy records).

```
UPDATE 
'customer.customers` 
SET emailHashCode = (SELECT 
TO_HEX(SHA256(e.emailAddress))
FROM
`customer.customers`,
UNNEST(emailAddresses) AS e LIMIT 1)
WHERE emailHashCode IS NULL
```

I get this error:

> Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of -62135600400000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field dateOfBirth

There's a dataOfBirth field in the table, but its not being touched. Curious if something basic is missing? Thanks for any clue!

Comment: The short summary (don't have time for an actual answer) is that you need to update the invalid timestamps as part of the same query, or in a preceding query.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottBrossard, fixing timestamps in millions of rows wasn't an option for me. Did it through data flow using a 'ParDo' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before jumping to your issue with timestamp - first, I wanted to mention that most likely your initial query is not correct - I would recommend you to consider below one instead (assuming that `emailAddresses` is repeated record with `emailAddress` field in it)

```sql
UPDATE 'customer.customers` 
SET emailHashCode = (
  SELECT TO_HEX(SHA256(e.emailAddress))
  FROM UNNEST(emailAddresses) AS e 
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE emailHashCode IS NULL
```

So, now back to your question: as Elliott has mentioned - you need to update the invalid timestamps as part of the same query. I haven't tested  - but try below

```sql
UPDATE 'customer.customers` 
SET emailHashCode = (
  SELECT TO_HEX(SHA256(e.emailAddress))
  FROM UNNEST(emailAddresses) AS e 
  LIMIT 1
), dateOfBirth = SAFE_CAST(dateOfBirth AS TIMESTAMP)
WHERE emailHashCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, easiest thing is to fix all the rows with bad `dataOfBirth` values.

I used `SAFE_CAST` to do this, try something like:

```
SAFE_CAST(dataOfBirth AS STRING) AS dataOfBirthString
```

Hope that helps!