# Creating table in BigQuery via API using Standard SQL Data Types

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to create a Table in BigQuery using the [com.google.cloud.bigquery](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html) Java API and during the process of building the schema I use the **Field.Builder method** to define the column names and data types.

```
ArrayList<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

fields.add(Field.newBuilder(columnName, LegacySQLTypeName.valueOf(columnType))
                                    .setMode(Field.Mode.valueOf(mode)).build());

Schema schema = Schema.of(fields);

TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(schema);

TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, tableDefinition).build();

Table table = bigquery.create(tableInfo);
```

However this only allows me to create a Table using LegacySQL which has no support for 'Date/Time' data types.

How can I create tables in BigQuery using Standard SQL Data types?

Comment: Did you see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement?

Comment: Yup I've had a look at that but I'm trying to create these tables in Java using the BigQuery API, don't really want to use SQL statements for that

Comment: If that's the case, then use `LegacySQLTypeName`, as in your question, with the Java API. You wrote, "this only allows me to create a Table using LegacySQL," which isn't true; you can use `DATE` and `TIME` as [in the enum](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/LegacySQLTypeName.html). After creating the table, nothing prevents you from using standard SQL to query it.

Comment: Problem is that it creates the table in a different format than if created using Standard SQL queries, for instance if I query the timestamp values in my table it says "Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of xxx microseconds relative to the Unix epoch time"

Comment: This issue is not related to how you create the table.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard So it seems to be invalidating the date and timestamp values from Postgres and causing a similar issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490579/bigquery-standard-sql-error-invalid-timestamp-when-date-field-is-not-touched-at?noredirect=1&lq=1), how do I get around this given the dates and timestamp values in postgres are valid?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to your original question. If you want to ask something else, submit a different question.